# best WYSIWYG editor from the UX side?

Tags: wysiwyg, files

There are a bunch of WYSIWYG edirtors available. I've tried CKEditor so far (and tinyMCE with wordpress). CKEditor is a very fancy one but fairly complex and weights 6Mb including source files.

What is in your experience the most buggless and stable?

It needs to have a support for IMCE bridge module to be able to get images from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use tinyMCE on my sites, it's not heavy, and you can use the IMCEbridge.

This module will install the **[WYSIWYG API](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)**, then follow **[these instructions](http://drupal.org/node/371459)** for adding TinyMCE or any other you want.

The IMCE Bridge module can be found **[here](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg)** and is compatible with *CKEditor*, *FCKeditor* and *TinyMCE*.

Comment: I think IMCEBridge is important so best choices are either ckeditor or tinyMCE